# Simple Linear Fractional Transformation Question

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $T$ is a linear fractional transformation such that $T(0)=1, T(1)=i,$ and $T(\infty)=0$.  Find $T(i)$ and describe $T(R)$, where R is the real line.

I ended up getting $T(z)=\frac{1}{(-i-1)z+1}$, and I am pretty sure this is correct.  I am lost on what $T(Z)$ does to the real line.

Comment: I don't see that your function satisfies $T(1) = i$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The way you formulated, $T(1) = \frac{1}{2+i}$. Are you sure you didn't mean $T(i)=i$?

Comment: Just fixed it - it reads correctly now.

Comment: I believe $T(R)$ is a circle centered at $\frac 12 + \frac 12i$ with radius $\frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: @Tunococ Do you have any reasoning behind this?

Comment: Every Moebius transformation takes a line or circle into a line or circle. The point at $\infty$ is a part of every line. As $T(\infty) = 0$ is not $\infty,$ it follows that any line, including the real line, is mapped to a circle passing through the origin. Very carefully, find $T(2), T(3), T(100), T(-1), T(-2), T(-100).$ You already know $T(0), T(1).$ Draw a careful picture.

Comment: While you are at it, do $$ T \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)   $$ and include that in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

As Will Jagy notes in the comments, $T$ takes a line to a line or a circle. Since $T$ takes $0,1,\infty$ to $1,i,0$, it takes the real line to a circle through $1$, $i$, and $0$. Think about that and you'll see we're talking about the circle that goes through the 4 corners of that little square, so it's centered at the center of that square, and its radius is half the diagonal of that square (in agreement with Tunococ's comment).